# Логика добавления записи в базы данных Access

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, ms-access

Разъясните логику записи строки в базу.
[image]

У меня есть форма, примерно такая: [image]

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при добавлении одной строки или нескольких в таблицу Заказ1(основная таблица), мне с начала нужно добавить эти значения в начальные таблицы (расписание, специальности, пациенты, услуги) при этом кликнув на кнопку Добавить, а потом уже, нажать Сохранить, чтобы эти значения по ключам попали в основную таблицу.

При этом, в форме, каждый textBox, это значение для начальных таблиц, т.е, для базы нужен один DataSet, и для каждой таблицы свой экземпляр DataAdapter что ты эти значения попали в основную таблицу?

Comment: Что сперва надо добавить запись в справочник, и только потом в связанную таблицу - правильно. А вот что для этого обязательно нужна спецкнопка - уже нет.

Comment: Никогда не используйте обычные данные, типа фамилии для связи данных в таблицах. Для этого есть первичные ключи. Фамилия может поменяться, можно в ней ошибиться, существуют однофамильцы, да и скорость работы при связывании по полям с целым цифровым типом данных выше.